# How do you prove $P \iff Q$ with modus tollens?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

I am totally knew to this sort of things, and I was not particularly good at mathematics in school, so forgive me if this is a stupid question. If you are going to prove $P \iff Q$ with modus tollens is this correct reasoning?

I should point out that $\iff$ does not have the same meaning as $\leftrightarrow$ so there is no confusion about the notation being used.

$P \iff Q$ is the same as saying that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is tautological. $P \leftrightarrow Q$ can be expressed as $(P \rightarrow Q) \wedge (Q \rightarrow P)$. So I will also assume that $P$ is given. I will rewrite $(Q \rightarrow P)$ as $(\neg Q \vee P)$.

Here is part of my attempt:

> 1.1 $P \rightarrow Q$  hyp
>
> 1.2 $P$ hyp
>
> 1.2.1 $\neg (\neg Q \vee P)$ asumption
>
> 1.2.2 $\neg P$ from 1.2.1
>
> 1.2.3 $\bot$ from 1.2 and 1.2.2
>
> 1.3 $(\neg Q \vee P)$
>
> 1 $(P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P) $

Correct so far? If not then how do you prove $P \iff Q$ with modus tollens?

Comment: $P\leftrightarrow Q$ is certainly NOT tautological -- it evaluates to false under the valuation where $P$ is true and $Q$ is false, for example.

Comment: No, $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is not tautological per se. However $P \iff Q$ denotes logical equivalence.which implies that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is tautological. To say that $P \iff Q$  is the same as saying that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is tautological per definition. If $P \iff Q$ it is given that $P \leftrightarrow Q$ is tautological.

Comment: $(\neg B \vee A)$ is a typo it should be $(\neg P \vee Q)$

Comment: Correction: $(\neg Q \vee P)$

Comment: The hypothesis P is still in effect when you got to ((P$\to$Q)$\to$(Q$\to$P)).

Comment: So how do you prove $P \iff Q$ with the use of modus tollens? I suspect that my attempt is incorrect.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, what you are saying is correct. However in this context $\iff$ is not used used for material equivalence, but logical equivalence, i.e. that it is the case that $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $Q \Rightarrow P$. $P \Rightarrow Q$ mean $P \vdash Q$ here.

Comment: @notmyrealname: That doesn't change anything here. $P$ and $Q$ are not logically equivalent, and neither $P\vdash Q$ nor $Q\vdash P$ hold. With your meaning of $\Longleftrightarrow$, your goal $P\iff Q$ _simply is not true_, and therefore can't be proved, with or without using modus tollens.